# How to make a variable that holds multiple lines by reading from a text file in batch or cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, variable-assignment

I have this text file containing multiple lines of text (message.txt)  and I wanted my variable have the value of it.

`set /p message=<message.txt`
this will only take the first line

`type message.txt`
will read the full text but i wasn't able to set is as a variable

Comment: Can you edit your [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75425510/edit) and add the contents of your `message.txt` and explain what API do you want to send to?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way

```
for /f "tokens=1delims==" %%b in ('set message') do set "%%b="

for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /n /R ".*" message.txt') do set "message%%b=%%c"
set message

for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b in ('set message') do echo %%c
```

The first `for` line clears all the `message` variables.

The second `for` line reads the data from the file; the `set` shows the values read

The third `for` line shows the values of the message variables.

Note that this simple method is limited to 9 lines (beyond that, you need to actually program the retrievel of the `message` variables) and will delete any leading <kbd>:</kbd> in any line of `message.txt`

Comment: But am not trying to echo them i wanted to send the text to an api

Comment: @KirubelDemelash Can you edit your [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75425510/edit) and add the contents of your `message.txt` and explain what API do you want to send to?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using an array in batch to store multiple lines of text read from a file.

---

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set idx=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("message.txt") do (
  set /a idx+=1
  set "line[!idx!]=%%i"
)

echo Number of lines: %idx%

for /l %%j in (1,1,%idx%) do (
  echo Line %%j: !line[%%j]!
)
pause
```

---

This code uses a for loop to read each line of the `message.txt` file and store each line in a separate element of the line array.

The variable `idx` is used to keep track of the number of lines read from the file.

After reading the file, the code outputs the number of lines and then uses another for loop to output each line stored in the line array.

Note the use of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to enable delayed expansion, which allows the use of variables within a block of code even if their values are changed within the block.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method to read a file is load each line in a different *array element*.. However, if you want to load all lines in *the same variable*, you can do it this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :readLines message=<message.txt

rem Standard expansion expands just the first line:
echo %message%

rem Delayed expansion expands all lines:
echo !message!

goto :EOF


:readLines variable < file

set /P "%1="
:nextLine
   set "line="
   set /P "line="
   if not defined line exit /B
   set ^"%1=!%1!^
%Don't remove this line%
%line%^"
goto nextLine
```